# Sass function to convert pixels to ems

Tags: sass

Take this function in Sass:

```
@function pem($pxval, $base: 16) {

         @return #{$pxval / $base}em ;
}
```

(source: https://gist.github.com/2237465)

`pem(16)` returns `1em` and it's ok, but `pem(16px)` returns `1pxem`.

how can this function accept both types of input?

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This seems like a good use for SASS's [unitless()](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#unitless-instance_method) function.

```
@function pem($pxval, $base: 16) {
  @if (unitless($pxval)) {
    $pxval: $pxval * 1px;
  }

  @if (unitless($base)) {
    $base: $base * 1px;
  }

  @return $pxval / $base * 1em;
}
```